# Turn a list of one dictionary into a list of two dictionaries using the same key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is my code:

```py
new_weights = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
myList = [{'weights': new_weights}]
```

This returns: `[{'weights': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]}]`

How could one get the following?

```
[{'weights': [1, 2, 3]}, {'weights': [4, 5, 6]}]
```

Comment: I suggest using a for loop.

Comment: @user, I have added an answer that might help you in case you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a list comprehension as follows:

```py
new_weights = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
myList = [{'weights': new_weights}]

result = [
    {'weights': element}
    for element in new_weights
]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'weights': [1, 2, 3]}, {'weights': [4, 5, 6]}]
```